# Is $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm learning limits and I was wondering is this true:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$$
Do limits have this property?

Comment: Yes, the cases that need to be excluded (without extra info on $f$ and $g$) are when the limits on the right *both* don't exist, or *both* go to zero, or *both* go to infinity.  In all other cases the equality is true for sure.

Comment: What if *g* goes to zero yet *f* doesn't? There's no trivial decent rule to divide by zero and still *g*'s sign should be concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have a lot of different cases:

If $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=0$ **and** $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b\ne0$ then **no**

If both $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ converge and not going to $0$ then **yes**

If the ratio between $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ diverge then **no**

If both $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ diverge then... We can't tell anything yet, we need to know more about $f(x),g(x)$

If both $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ are equal $0$ then we still can't tell anything yet, we need to know more about $f(x),g(x)$

If $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ diverge to infinity are still can't tell anything yet, we need to know more about $f(x),g(x)$

If $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ diverge between $2$ numbers ($\limsup_{x\to a}f(x)\ne \liminf_{x\to a}f(x)$) then **no**

Answer (score 2):

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ **exist** and if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x) \ne 0$, then you have:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$$

Comment: Not quite, $f$ and $g$ can also diverge on $a$, but not the ratio...

Comment: @Martigan I only gave an **if**-statement (and didn't comment on the converse) but I'll rephrase to emphasize the correct implication (I intended).

Comment: The answer says **if**, not ‘if and only if’.

Answer (score 1):

If $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrowtail\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in((\text{dom}(f))'\cap(\text{dom}(g))')$ and $\exists \lim\limits_af=F, \lim\limits_ag=G$, then:
- $\exists \lim\limits_a(f+g)=F+G$
- $\exists \lim\limits_a(fg)=FG$
- if $G\neq0$ then $\exists \lim\limits_a\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)=\frac{F}{G}$

Comment: $(+1)$ for the great answer, and for the fact that someone bothered to write the symbol, $\rightarrowtail$ :P

Comment: @user477343 Thank you :) My teacher used the $f: E \rightarrowtail F$ when $\text{dom}(f) \subseteq E$, and $g: E \rightarrow F$ when $\text{dom}(g) = E$

Comment: Yeah most people get lazy and just right the arrows like $\to$. But you and your teacher didn't, and I respect that. Notation does not define math, but it definitely makes it look that bit prettier :P

Comment: @user477343 Yes :) Personally, I like to use a variety of notations, based on my mood, the topic, and the conversation partner. A good example might be the Einstein notation, or $\int f(x) \mathrm{d} x$ vs $\int \mathrm{d} x f(x)$.